# Not able to search from Google.com, as I am getting the error " Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.".why ?

Tags: linux, google-search-api

Not able to search from Google.com, as I am getting the error " Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network." However I am able to go to any other site directly. Do anyone have any idea?
I am using a Linux OS

Comment: have you used google.com more than one browser?

Answer (score 0):

You may have malware running automated searches against google...

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google has smart ways of figuring out if your query is a bot. They do this by checking your URL pattern. If your pattern is similar, with the same parameters, etc, they will easily detect it and block your IP and any other IPs that your bot is using. That block can last 30 minutes or longer.